# Web3js - "The returned value is not a convertible string"

Tags: solidity, web3js

Can someone please help me. While trying to invoke a constant function which returns string, I am getting

> "Promise RejectedError: ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible
>   string:"

**Contract Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract LandTitles {

    struct Title {
        string latitude;
        string longitude;
        string geoAddress;
        string ownerName;
    }
mapping(address => Title) titles;

function first(){

}

function register(string latitudeOfLand, 
                    string longitudeOfLand, 
                    string geoAddressOfLand, 
                    string ownerNameOfLand){
    titles[msg.sender].latitude = latitudeOfLand;
    titles[msg.sender].longitude = longitudeOfLand;
    titles[msg.sender].geoAddress = geoAddressOfLand;
    titles[msg.sender].ownerName = ownerNameOfLand;
}

function getTitle() constant returns(string, string, string, string){
    return (titles[msg.sender].latitude, titles[msg.sender].longitude, titles[msg.sender].geoAddress, titles[msg.sender].ownerName);    

}

function getLatitude() constant returns(string){
    return (titles[msg.sender].latitude);    
}

function getMyAddress() constant returns(string){
    return strConcat(titles[msg.sender].latitude,
            titles[msg.sender].longitude,titles[msg.sender].ownerName);
}


function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c, string _d, string _e) constant returns (string){
    bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
    bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
    bytes memory _bc = bytes(_c);
    bytes memory _bd = bytes(_d);
    bytes memory _be = bytes(_e);
    string memory abcde = new string(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length + _bd.length + _be.length);
    bytes memory babcde = bytes(abcde);
    uint k = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _ba[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bb[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bc[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _bd.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bd[i];
    for (i = 0; i < _be.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _be[i];
    return string(babcde);
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c, string _d)  constant returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, _d, "");
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b, string _c) constant returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, "", "");
}

function strConcat(string _a, string _b) constant returns (string) {
    return strConcat(_a, _b, "", "", "");
}
}
```

---

**Client code:**

```
var myContractAbi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"latitudeOfLand","type":"string"},{"name":"longitudeOfLand","type":"string"},{"name":"geoAddressOfLand","type":"string"},{"name":"ownerNameOfLand","type":"string"}],"name":"register","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"first","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_a","type":"string"},{"name":"_b","type":"string"},{"name":"_c","type":"string"}],"name":"strConcat","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_a","type":"string"},{"name":"_b","type":"string"},{"name":"_c","type":"string"},{"name":"_d","type":"string"}],"name":"strConcat","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_a","type":"string"},{"name":"_b","type":"string"},{"name":"_c","type":"string"},{"name":"_d","type":"string"},{"name":"_e","type":"string"}],"name":"strConcat","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMyAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getLatitude","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getTitle","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_a","type":"string"},{"name":"_b","type":"string"}],"name":"strConcat","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];

var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbi);

var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbi,"0xD2010925d2C5b3ac3Cbde585d79C32af417946Ee");

// call constant function
var myresult = myContractInstance.methods.getLatitude().call();

console.log("contract result-:");

Promise.resolve(myresult).then(function(value) {
  console.log('value: ' + value);
}).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("Promise Rejected"+error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AchalaDissanayake do you mean on the client? The problem is it is not even going inside the function for .then

Comment: In the following block -              Promise.resolve(myresult).then(function(value) {
  console.log('value: ' + value);
}).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("Promise Rejected"+error);
});                                                                                                                                   ---- this block prints Promise RejectedError: ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string:

Comment: yeah, inside that can you replace `console.log('value: ' + value); ` with `console.log('value: ' +Buffer.toString(value));` and check?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't go in that function, a console.log("something") also doesn't get printed because it directly goes to catch function.

Comment: did you register a value from the same address before getting it?

Comment: yes yes, I did. Infact if I run the same function in remix ide it works fine.

Comment: try returning a hard coded string value like `return "return value";` inside `getLatitude()`  and check client app

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake thanks for your help. I have been able to resolve this issue and I'll document my findings in answer to this question.

Comment: great :) That's good.

Comment: I encounter this error? could you help me please? ## my contract method: >function getAuthor() public pure returns(string result){ return "Allence";
} ## I use the method:
>mycontract.methods.getAuthor().call(console.log) ## my config
> solc: 0.4.21 web3.js:1.0

Comment: if you have another question open your own post https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask yet your syntax is wrong, it should be: mycontract.methods.getAuthor().call().then(console.log)

Answer (score 1):

web3 cannot handle strings which will be returned from a solidity function. You have to return a bytes32 value. I recommend that you store your values (latitude, longitude etc) as bytes32 values and return them from your functions as bytes32 values.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a whole day I have been able to get around the stupid confusion of contract address and account sender address. That was the reason for this error.

While instantiating a contract use **contract address**,

`var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbi,"**<contract address>**");`.

While calling even a static method use **account address**,

`var myresult = myContractInstance.methods.getTitle().call({"from": "**<account address>**"});`.

Comment: IMHO a better interface is declaring `function getTitle(address user) view returns (string..) { return (titles[user].latitude..); }`. As a bonus you can call it from another contract.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. This error appeared for me and setting `from` did not fix it. Furthermore, I have other instances where I'm doing `call`s without specifying a sender.