# Calling method to return stored string results in error: The returned value is not a convertible string

Tags: solidity, web3js, ipfs, rinkeby

I am trying out a very simple contract on the Rinkeby testnet. Pretty much as simple as it gets:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Root {
    string rootHash;

    function set(string x) public {
        rootHash = x;
    }

    function get() public constant returns (string x) {
        return rootHash;
    }

}
```

It stores an ipfs multihash, and allows retrieving it.

The write part seems to work, using this code:
https://gist.github.com/pwrstudio/6c95043ae3bb6a9aef9734a3fc8469e7

I can see that the multihash is sent to the contract, encoded as hex:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4d7b98cf577d580168d24b1f61bcbc60f3f919c751624793e83dd10191ebba98

But when calling the `get` function I get this error:

```
ERROR: The returned value is not a convertible string
```

Relevant js code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const rootContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS)
  rootContract.methods
    .get()
    .call()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
})
```

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deploy a contract, then send and retrieve a string from it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30763/how-do-i-deploy-a-contract-then-send-and-retrieve-a-string-from-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web3js - "The returned value is not a convertible string"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26966/web3js-the-returned-value-is-not-a-convertible-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small typo in the definition of function `get`. You should define only the return type `string` in the function definition, but no variable name (`x`). This should make it work:

```
function get() public constant returns (string) {
    return rootHash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it. (Turned out I had also specified to low gas limit for the set function call, causing it to fail, but with those two problems fixed, everything works.)